# Lifecycle of Activity and containing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Say I have an `Activity` that has a `Fragment` embedded via it's XML layout like:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/detaillist"
    android:name="com.example.DetailListFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

In the `Fragment` I depend on something that happens in the `Activity`'s `onCreate` method. At what `Fragment` lifecycle callback can I be sure that the `Activity`'s `onCreate` is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}
```

This function of the `Fragment` will help you to know `onCreate` of Activity is done. Hope this will help.

Comment: That makes sense. Should have had another look at the fragment lifecycle. Thanks!

Comment: I will in 2 minutes (SO let's you accept only after some time).

Comment: just complementing because a picture is worth a thousand words:
http://docs.xamarin.com/static/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/Images/fragment_lifecycle.png